# Ошибка RuntimeWarning после выполнения команды в discord боте

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пишу discord бота(discord.py) на Python. После выполнения команды /select_faculty я получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_override' was never awaited
  ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Вот код:

```
        faculties = {
            "grif": 0,
            "sliz": 0,
            "huff": 0,
            "raven": 0
        }
        who = ""
        faculty = ""
        question1_emb = discord.Embed(title="Давай пройдём небольшой тест.", colour=discord.Colour.green(),
                                      description="Первый вопрос - какой ты?:")
        question2_emb = discord.Embed(title="Второй вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.orange(),
                                      description="Какое животное тебе нравится больше всего?")
        question3_emb = discord.Embed(title="Третий вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.purple(),
                                      description="Какая стихия нравится тебе больше всего?")
        question4_emb = discord.Embed(title="Четвёртый вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
                                      description="Какие комбинации цветов нравятся тебе больше всего?")
        question5_emb = discord.Embed(title="Пятый вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.red(),
                                      description="Какое привидение из Хогвартса нравится тебе больше всего?")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=who_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Ученик с жаждой знаний", emoji="‍")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Мудрый наставник", emoji="")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Министр магии", emoji="‍⚖️")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Ученик с жаждой знаний":
            who = "apprentice"
            await answer.delete()
        elif response.component.label == "Мудрый наставник":
            who = "mentor"
            await answer.delete()
        elif response.component.label == "Министр магии":
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Ты не пройдёшь!!!", colour=discord.Colour.red()))
        answer = await member.send(embed=question1_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Храбрый"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Хитрый")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Упорный"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Мудрый")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Храбрый":
            faculties["grif"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Хитрый":
            faculties["sliz"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Упорный":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Мудрый":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question2_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Лев"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Змея"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Барсук"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Орёл")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Лев":
            faculties["grif"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Змея":
            faculties["sliz"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Барсук":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Орёл":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question3_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Огонь"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Вода"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Земля"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Воздух")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Огонь":
            faculties["grif"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Вода":
            faculties["sliz"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Земля":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Воздух":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question4_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Красный и жёлтый"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Зелёный и серебрянный")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Жёлтый и чёрный"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Синий и бронзовый")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Красный и жёлтый":
            faculties["grif"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Зелёный и серебрянный":
            faculties["sliz"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Жёлтый и чёрный":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Синий и бронзовый":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question5_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Почти Безголовый Ник"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Кровавый Барон")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Толстый Монах"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Серая Дама")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Почти Безголовый Ник":
            faculties["grif"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Кровавый Барон":
            faculties["sliz"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Толстый Монах":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Серая Дама":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        for k, v in faculties.items():
            if v == max(faculties.values()):
                faculty = k
        for role in [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]:
            if role != "@everyone" and role in channel_roles.keys():
                user_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.author.roles, name=role)
                await member.remove_roles(user_role)
        await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles[who][faculty]))
```

Comment: 1. В какой строчке конкретно происходит Ваша ошибка? И что должна выполнять Ваша функция?
2. Какую Вы библиотеку, кроме discordpy, для компонентов? И как у Вас версия discordpy (2.0 альфа или стабильная 1.7.3)?
3. Какие намерения (intents) запрашиваете?
4. Выданы ли соответствующие права роли бота в настройках сервера?

Comment: 1. Строку с ошибкой найти не получается. Функция должна на основе ответов 
на вопросы пользователя давать ему роль на сервере. 2. Для компонентов - discord_components. Версия 1.7.3. 3. Запрашиваю members. 4. Да, выданы.

Comment: Можешь отредактировать вопрос и вставить всю функцию, а также часть кода, который она использует?

Comment: Вы так не показали более подробно Ваш код, поэтому я показал свое решение с использованием своих инструментов. Пишите, если Вам ещё понадобиться помощь или Вас что-то будет не устраивать в моем ответе. Код должен работать и на версии 1.7.3 discordpy. А вот для discord_components потребуются изменения. Также при изменение сообщения с компонентами могут появляться странные ситуации. Лично у меня, когда я изменял сообщения после нажатия кнопки, то почему-то нажималась автоматически новая кнопка и выдавало ошибку взаимодействия. А после можно было нажать на кнопку, и всё работало.

Comment: Я изменил код под `discord.py 1.7.3` и `discord-components 2.1.2`. Если Вас ответ устраивает, то [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Я использую `discord.py 2.0.0a3575+g45d498c` и `dislash.py 1.4.9`. Надеюсь этот код Вам поможет или даст идею хотя бы.

config.py

```py
ds_token = '<token>'
guild_ids = {<guild_id>}
owner_ids = {<your_id>}
bot_prefix = '<command_prefix>'
```

index.py

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from discord import commands
import discord as ds
import dislash as dl
import asyncio
import config

bot = commands.Bot(commands.when_mentioned_or(config.bot_prefix), owner_ids=config.owner_ids)
slash = dl.InteractionClient(bot, test_guilds=config.guild_ids)

@slash.slash_command()
async def select_faculty(ctx):
    questions = [
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Давай пройдём небольшой тест.',
                colour=ds.Colour.green(),
                description='Первый вопрос - какой ты?'
            ),
            [
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Храбрый',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Хитрый',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Упорный',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                        label='Мудрый',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Второй вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.orange(),
                description='Какое животное тебе нравится больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Лев',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Змея',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Барсук',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                        label='Орёл',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Третий вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.purple(),
                description='Какая стихия нравится тебе больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Огонь',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Вода',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Земля',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                        label='Воздух',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Четвёртый вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.blue(),
                description='Какие комбинации цветов нравятся тебе больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Красный и Жёлтый',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Зелёный и Серебряный',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Жёлтый и Чёрный',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                        label='Синий и Бронзовый',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Пятый вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.red(),
                description='Какое привидение из Хогвартса нравится тебе больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Почти Безголовый Ник',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Кровавый Барон',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                dl.ActionRow(
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Толстый Монах',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    dl.Button(
                        style=dl.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                        label='Серая Дама',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
    ]
    
    message = await ctx.reply(
        embed=ds.Embed(
            title='Кем ты хочешь стать?',
            colour=ds.Colour.green(),
        ),
        components=[
            dl.ActionRow(
                dl.Button(
                    style=dl.ButtonStyle.green,
                    label='Ученик с жаждой знаний',
                    emoji='‍',
                    custom_id='apprentice'
                ),
                dl.Button(
                    style=dl.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                    label='Мудрый наставник',
                    emoji='',
                    custom_id='mentor'
                ),
                dl.Button(
                    style=dl.ButtonStyle.red,
                    label='Министр магии',
                    emoji='‍⚖️',
                    custom_id='impossible'
                )
            )
        ]
    )
    
    try:
        inter = await message.wait_for_button_click(timeout=60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await message.reply(
                embed=ds.Embed(
                    title='Слииишком долго!',
                    colour=ds.Colour.red(),
                    description='Ты долго слишком долго не отвечал.'
                )
            )
    
    who = inter.component.custom_id
    if who == 'impossible':
        return await inter.reply(
            embed=ds.Embed(
                    title='Ты не пройдёшь!!!',
                    colour=ds.Colour.red()
                ) 
            )
        
    faculties = {
        'gryffindor': 0,
        'slytherin': 0,
        'hufflepuff': 0,
        'ravenclaw': 0,
    }
        
    for embed, components in questions:
        message = await inter.reply(
            embed=embed,
            components=components
        )

        try:
            inter = await message.wait_for_button_click(timeout=60)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await message.reply(
                    embed=ds.Embed(
                        title='Слииишком долго!',
                        colour=ds.Colour.red(),
                        description='Ты долго слишком долго не отвечал.'
                    )
                )
        
        faculties[inter.clicked_button.custom_id] += 1    

    roles = (
        'apprentice_gryffindor',
        'apprentice_slytherin',
        'apprentice_hufflepuff',
        'apprentice_ravenclaw',
        'mentor_gryffindor',
        'mentor_slytherin',
        'mentor_hufflepuff',
        'mentor_ravenclaw',
    )
    
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(
        *(ds.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role) for role in roles)
    )
    
    # OR
    # roles = ( # tuple of role id's
    #    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    # )
    # 
    # await ctx.author.remove_roles(
    #     *(ctx.guild.get_role(role) for role in roles)
    # )
    
    faculty = max(faculties, key=lambda faculty: faculties[faculty]) 
    role = ds.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=f'{who}_{faculty}')
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    
    await inter.reply(
        embed=ds.Embed(
            title='Твой факультет...',
            colour=ds.Colour.green(),
            description={
                f'{who}_gryffindor': 'Гриффиндор',
                f'{who}_slytherin': 'Слизерин',
                f'{who}_hufflepuff': 'Пуффендуй',
                f'{who}_ravenclaw': 'Когтевран',
            }.get(role.name)
        )
    )

bot.run(config.ds_token, reconnect=True)
```

**UPD:**

Изменил под `discord.py 1.7.3` и `discord-components 2.1.2`.

index.py

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from discord_components import (
    ComponentsBot,
    Interaction,
    ButtonStyle,
    ActionRow,
    Button,
)

from discord.ext import commands
import discord as ds
import asyncio
import config

bot = ComponentsBot(commands.when_mentioned_or(config.bot_prefix), owner_ids=config.owner_ids)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@bot.command()
async def select_faculty(ctx):
    async def wait_button(message):
        try:
            return await bot.wait_for(
                event='button_click',
                check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id and inter.user == ctx.author,
                timeout=60
            )
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await message.reply(
                embed=ds.Embed(
                    title='Слииишком долго!',
                    colour=ds.Colour.red(),
                    description='Ты долго слишком долго не отвечал.'
                )
            )
    
    questions = [
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Давай пройдём небольшой тест.',
                colour=ds.Colour.green(),
                description='Первый вопрос - какой ты?'
            ),
            [
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Храбрый',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Хитрый',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Упорный',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                        label='Мудрый',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Второй вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.orange(),
                description='Какое животное тебе нравится больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Лев',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Змея',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Барсук',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                        label='Орёл',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Третий вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.purple(),
                description='Какая стихия нравится тебе больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Огонь',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Вода',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Земля',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                        label='Воздух',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Четвёртый вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.blue(),
                description='Какие комбинации цветов нравятся тебе больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Красный и Жёлтый',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Зелёный и Серебряный',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Жёлтый и Чёрный',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                        label='Синий и Бронзовый',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        (
            ds.Embed(
                title='Пятый вопрос:',
                colour=ds.Colour.red(),
                description='Какое привидение из Хогвартса нравится тебе больше всего?'
            ),
            [
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.red,
                        label='Почти Безголовый Ник',
                        custom_id='gryffindor'
                        ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.green,
                        label='Кровавый Барон',
                        custom_id='slytherin'
                    )
                ),
                ActionRow(
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.gray,
                        label='Толстый Монах',
                        custom_id='hufflepuff'
                    ),
                    Button(
                        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                        label='Серая Дама',
                        custom_id='ravenclaw'
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
    ]
    
    message = await ctx.reply(
        embed=ds.Embed(
            title='Кем ты хочешь стать?',
            colour=ds.Colour.green(),
        ),
        components=[
            ActionRow(
                Button(
                    style=ButtonStyle.green,
                    label='Ученик с жаждой знаний',
                    emoji='‍',
                    custom_id='apprentice'
                ),
                Button(
                    style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                    label='Мудрый наставник',
                    emoji='',
                    custom_id='mentor'
                ),
                Button(
                    style=ButtonStyle.red,
                    label='Министр магии',
                    emoji='‍⚖️',
                    custom_id='impossible'
                )
            )
        ]
    )
    
    inter: Interaction = await wait_button(message)
    
    if (who := inter.custom_id) == 'impossible':
        return await inter.send(
            ephemeral=False,
            embed=ds.Embed(
                    title='Ты не пройдёшь!!!',
                    colour=ds.Colour.red()
                ),
            )
        
    faculties = {
        'gryffindor': 0,
        'slytherin': 0,
        'hufflepuff': 0,
        'ravenclaw': 0,
    }
        
    for embed, components in questions:
        message = await inter.send(
            embed=embed, components=components, ephemeral=False,
        )
        inter = await wait_button(message)
        faculties[inter.custom_id] += 1

    roles = (
        'apprentice_gryffindor',
        'apprentice_slytherin',
        'apprentice_hufflepuff',
        'apprentice_ravenclaw',
        'mentor_gryffindor',
        'mentor_slytherin',
        'mentor_hufflepuff',
        'mentor_ravenclaw',
    )
    
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(
        *(ds.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role) for role in roles)
    )
    
    # OR
    # roles = ( # tuple of role id's
    #    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    # )
    # 
    # await ctx.author.remove_roles(
    #     *(ctx.guild.get_role(role) for role in roles)
    # )
    
    faculty = max(faculties, key=lambda faculty: faculties[faculty]) 
    role = ds.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=f'{who}_{faculty}')
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    
    await inter.reply(
        embed=ds.Embed(
            title='Твой факультет...',
            colour=ds.Colour.green(),
            description={
                f'{who}_gryffindor': 'Гриффиндор',
                f'{who}_slytherin': 'Слизерин',
                f'{who}_hufflepuff': 'Пуффендуй',
                f'{who}_ravenclaw': 'Когтевран',
            }[role.name]
        )
    )

bot.run(config.ds_token, reconnect=True)
```