# Discord бот неправильно работает, если несколько участников пытаются получить роль одновременно

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пишу discord бота (discord.py) и мне нужна функция, которая будет добавлять участнику роли сразу (пользователь может выбрать роль сам) или в при прохождении теста (который отправляется участнику в ЛС). Вот то, что я написал:

```
@bot.command()
async def select_faculty(ctx):
    """Функция select_faculty позволяет выбрать сразу или пройти тест для
    определения факультета.
    """
    member = ctx.message.author
    channel_roles = [
        "gryffindor - ученик",
        "slytherin - ученик",
        "hufflepuff - ученик",
        "ravenclaw - ученик",
        "gryffindor - наставник",
        "slytherin - наставник",
        "hufflepuff - наставник",
        "ravenclaw - наставник",
        "ждущие зачисления",
        "ученик",
        "наставник",
    ]
    start_emb = discord.Embed(title="Приветствую тебя, маг!", colour=discord.Colour.orange(),
                              description="Выбери вариант распределения:")
    who_emb = discord.Embed(title="Для начала выбери кто ты:", colour=discord.Colour.purple())
    select_fac_emb = discord.Embed(title="Выбери факультет:", colour=discord.Colour.red(),
                                   description="Выбери понравившийся тебе факультет.")
    send_fac_menu = ctx.send(embed=select_fac_emb, components=[
        [Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Гриффиндор", emoji=""),
         Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Слизерин", emoji="")],
        [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Когтевран", emoji=""),
         Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Пуффендуй", emoji="")],
        [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Пожиратели смерти", emoji="")]
    ])
    answer = await ctx.channel.send(embed=start_emb, components=[[
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Выбрать сразу"),
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Пройти тест")]])
    response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
    await response.edit_origin()
    if response.component.label == "Выбрать сразу":
        for role in [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]:
            if role != "@everyone" and role.lower() in channel_roles:
                user_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.author.roles, name=role)
                await member.remove_roles(user_role)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await ctx.send(embed=who_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Ученик с жаждой знаний", emoji="‍")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Мудрый наставник", emoji="")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Ученик с жаждой знаний":
            await send_fac_menu
            response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
            await response.edit_origin()
            if response.component.label == "Гриффиндор":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["apprentice"]["gryff"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Слизерин":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["apprentice"]["slyth"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Когтевран":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["apprentice"]["raven"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Пуффендуй":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["apprentice"]["huff"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Пожиратели смерти":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["apprentice"]["death"]))
            await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["apprentice"]["apprentice"]))
            await answer.delete()
        elif response.component.label == "Мудрый наставник":
            await send_fac_menu
            response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
            await response.edit_origin()
            if response.component.label == "Гриффиндор":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["mentor"]["gryff"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Слизерин":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["mentor"]["slyth"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Когтевран":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["mentor"]["raven"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Пуффендуй":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["mentor"]["huff"]))
            elif response.component.label == "Пожиратели смерти":
                await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["mentor"]["death"]))
            await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles["mentor"]["mentor"]))
            await answer.delete()
    elif response.component.label == "Пройти тест":
        faculties = {
            "gryff": 0,
            "slyth": 0,
            "huff": 0,
            "raven": 0
        }
        who = ""
        faculty = ""
        question1_emb = discord.Embed(title="Давай пройдём небольшой тест.", colour=discord.Colour.green(),
                                      description="Первый вопрос - какой ты?:")
        question2_emb = discord.Embed(title="Второй вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.orange(),
                                      description="Какое животное тебе нравится больше всего?")
        question3_emb = discord.Embed(title="Третий вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.purple(),
                                      description="Какая стихия нравится тебе больше всего?")
        question4_emb = discord.Embed(title="Четвёртый вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
                                      description="Какие комбинации цветов нравятся тебе больше всего?")
        question5_emb = discord.Embed(title="Пятый вопрос:", colour=discord.Colour.red(),
                                      description="Какое привидение из Хогвартса нравится тебе больше всего?")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=who_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Ученик с жаждой знаний", emoji="‍")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Мудрый наставник", emoji="")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Министр магии", emoji="‍⚖️")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Ученик с жаждой знаний":
            who = "apprentice"
        elif response.component.label == "Мудрый наставник":
            who = "mentor"
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question1_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Храбрый"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Хитрый")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Упорный"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Мудрый")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Храбрый":
            faculties["gryff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Хитрый":
            faculties["slyth"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Упорный":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Мудрый":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question2_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Лев"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Змея"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Барсук"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Орёл")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Лев":
            faculties["gryff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Змея":
            faculties["slyth"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Барсук":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Орёл":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question3_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Огонь"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Вода"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Земля"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Воздух")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Огонь":
            faculties["gryff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Вода":
            faculties["slyth"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Земля":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Воздух":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question4_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Красный и жёлтый"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Зелёный и серебрянный")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Жёлтый и чёрный"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Синий и бронзовый")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Красный и жёлтый":
            faculties["gryff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Зелёный и серебрянный":
            faculties["slyth"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Жёлтый и чёрный":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Синий и бронзовый":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        answer = await member.send(embed=question5_emb, components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Почти Безголовый Ник"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Кровавый Барон")],
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.gray, label="Толстый Монах"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Серая Дама")]
        ])
        response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        await response.edit_origin()
        if response.component.label == "Почти Безголовый Ник":
            faculties["gryff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Кровавый Барон":
            faculties["slyth"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Толстый Монах":
            faculties["huff"] += 1
        elif response.component.label == "Серая Дама":
            faculties["raven"] += 1
        await answer.delete()
        for k, v in faculties.items():
            if v == max(faculties.values()):
                faculty = k
        for role in [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]:
            if role != "@everyone" and role.lower() in channel_roles:
                user_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.author.roles, name=role)
                await member.remove_roles(user_role)
        emb = discord.Embed(title=f"Вы зачислены в {faculty}!", colour=discord.Colour.green())
        await member.send(embed=emb)
        await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles[who][faculty]))
        await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.guild.roles, id=roles[who][who]))
```

Но возникает одна проблема - если роль выбирают сразу несколько участников, то бот начинает неадекватно работать: в тесте использует ответы других пользователей, чтобы добавить тебе роль, когда участник нажимает на кнопку, он получает ошибку взаимодействия, ещё бот выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Ignoring exception in command select_faculty:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\main.py", line 226, in select_faculty
    await response.edit_origin()
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_components\interaction.py", line 244, in edit_origin
    await self.defer(edit_origin=True)
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_components\interaction.py", line 93, in defer
    await self.respond(type=5 if not edit_origin else 6, ephemeral=ephemeral)
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_components\interaction.py", line 185, in respond
    raise NotFound(
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 0): Interaction is unknown (you have already responded to the interaction or responding took too long)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сразу несколько пользователей могли выбрать роль?

Comment: Так как проблема на стороне сервиса - например сделать для данного типа запросов в сервис очередь или стек.

Comment: А можете показать как реализовать стек на примере одного из блоков моего кода? А то я вроде бы знаю, как сделать стек, но не знаю как подойти к его реализации в коде бота.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае у Вас ошибка в `response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")`. Вы ждете просто нажатие **любой** кнопки, даже у других пользователей. Добавьте условие проверки.

```py
def check(inter):
    return inter.message.id == message.id and inter.user == ctx.author

await bot.wait_for(event='button_click', check=check)
```

P.S. Ранее я отвечал на Ваш [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1346060/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-runtimewarning-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-discord-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5) ([ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1346550/436670)). Что Вас не удовлетворило в моей прошлой реализации?